# what am I missing here? Basic Java

Tags: java

```
public class Calculator {

  Calculator() {
    }

  public int add(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
  }

  public int subtract(int a, int b) {
    return a - b;
  } 

  public int multiply(int a, int b) {
    return a * b;
  }

  public int divide(int a, int b) {
    return a/b;
    if(b == 0) {
      System.out.println("Error! Dividing by zero is not allowed.");
      return 0;
    else {
      return a/b;
    }  
    }
  }

  public int modulo(int a, int b) {
    if(b == 0) {
      System.out.println("Error! Dividing by zero is not allowed.");
      return 0;
    else {
      return a % b;
    }
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Calculator myCalculator = new Calculator();
    System.out.println(myCalculator.add(5, 7));
    System.out.println(myCalculator.subtract(12, 34));
    }
}
```

Errors that appear:

Calculator.java:23: error: 'else' without 'if'
    else {

Calculator.java:33: error: 'else' without 'if'
    else {

Still beginner so if you wanna add some tips I'd apreciate it.

Comment: Your curly braces are mismatched.

Comment: _All_ of your curly braces are mismatched...

Comment: Move the third last `}` up two lines in `modulo()` and `divide()`. And delete the first `return` in `divide()`.

Comment: how do I fix it?

Comment: `if(b == 0) { ... } else { ... }`

Comment: And you have dead code after the first `return` in the method `divide` - the return always returns control from there so the following if-statement is never reached. Remove the first `return` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't close correctly sentence IF in the method "divide" and "modulo".
Example:

```
public int divide(int a, int b) {
    return a/b;
    if(b == 0) {
      System.out.println("Error! Dividing by zero is not allowed.");
      return 0;
    }else {
      return a/b;  
    }
  }
```